# Is there a way to insert an encrypted script into a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

My company considers database scripts we write part of our intellectual property.

With new releases, we deliver a 2-part setup for our users:

- a desktop application
- an executable that wraps up the complexities of initializing/updating a database (RedGate SQL Packager).

I know I can encrypt a stored procedure on a database once the script is present, but is there any way to ***insert*** it in an encrypted form? I don't want plain-text to be able to be intercepted across the "wire" (or more accurately, between the SQL script executable and the server).

I'm not really tied to the tool we're using - I just want to know if it's possible without having to resort to something hokey.

Comment: Encrypted procedures are able to be almost trivially decrypted. If you can't trust your customers, I don't think this is going to help.

Comment: @BenThul While you are correct, the OP's expressed concern was about being intercepted across the wire, not decryption by customers.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: The way the question is worded, it seems like the OP is trying to prevent their customer from ever seeing the proc. I'm going to assume that the client has the ability to run profiler (or equivalent) against their own server. Any DDL statement z(even encoded ones like your solution below) can be captured through such a mechanism.

Comment: @BenThul The question says nothing at all like that.  It express concern about being "*intercepted across the 'wire'*".  This is an entirely different threat domain from user's on the SQL Server and has nothing at all to do with who has what privileges on the target.

Comment: Then use SSL to connect to the server and call it a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Enctyptpassphrase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx) and [DecryptPassPharse](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910.aspx) functions.

Use ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE to encrypt all your DDL statements and then DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE on the server to decrypt and execute.

```
declare @encrypt varbinary(200) 
select @encrypt = EncryptByPassPhrase('key', 'your script goes here' )
select @encrypt 

select convert(varchar(100),DecryptByPassPhrase('key', @encrypt ))
```

Create a procedure that would look like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.ExecuteDDL
(
@script varbinary(max) 
)
  AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = (select convert(varchar(max),DecryptByPassPhrase('key', @script )))

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL        
END
```

Once this is in place you can publish scripts to your server like this

Answer (score 0):

This isn't plain-text and last I checked, it still works:

```
declare @_ as varbinary(max)
set @_ =0x0D000A005000520049004E0054002000270054006800690073002000620069006E00610072007900200073007400720069006E0067002000770069006C006C002000650078006500630075007400650020002200530045004C0045004300540020002A002000460052004F004D0020005300590053002E004F0042004A00450043005400530022003A0027000D000A00530045004C0045004300540020002A002000460052004F004D0020005300590053002E004F0042004A0045004300540053000D000A00
exec (@_)
```

Technically, it's not encryption, but it's not plaintext either and it can server as the basis for some mild encryption pretty easily.

Comment: Nice trick, I didn't knew it was even possible. Unfortunately, it's trivial to decrypt too, as a simple cast to nvarchar(max) returns the plain text

Comment: what if your `@_` contained something like recursive table drops ?

Comment: sir it was just a joke !

Answer (score 0):

There's little you can do to reliably prevent the code in the database to be read by anyone who **really** wants. The `WITH ENCRYPTION` parameter is really just an obfuscation and many simple scripts are able to get it again in plain text, and when the database is being upgraded, ultimately the profiler will always be able to catch the `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement with the full text. Network tracers can be evaded by using an encrypted connection to the server.

The real problem comes from the fact that the database is installed in a server that your users own and fully control (correct me if that's not the case). No matter what you do, they'll have full access to the whole database, it's schema, and internal programming inside sprocs/functions.

The closest I can think of to prevent that is to switch to CLR stored procedures, which are installed by copying a DLL to the server and registering within SQL Server. They pose other problems, as they are totally different to program and may not be the best tool for what you use a sproc normally. Also, since the are made of standard .NET code, they can also be trivially decompiled.

The only way I can think of fully protecting the database structure and code would be to put it in a server of yours, that you expose to your customers though, say, a webservice or a handful of sprocs as wrappers, so no one can peek inside.

Comment: You completely missed the point of what the OP was requesting.  Nothing was said about protecting it in the database or from the  users.

Comment: Then, what was the request? Protect what from who?