# Run a bulk of encrypted Sql queries sequentially via Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, encryption, ssms

My company has written a long and lengthy migration script that we run on our customers servers (either manually or as a job via *Sql Server Management Studio*). But since a rival company also has access to the customer server, the script can be easily plagiarized.

I am wondering if we could run the script using the following scenario:

[image]

So we have 3 parameters that the script needs in order to run and then there is a bulk of encrypted text that contain the actual script. We can assume one of the parameters is the key to decryption.

When we execute the script, Sql server reads the parameter, and then decrypts and runs the encrypted bulk of queries sequentially as if they are not encrypted to begin with.

I know this all can be traced via *Sql Profiler* and via queries that show history if logs. But for now this can block the viewer sitting on the server side to copy our algorithm that has taken us a long time to develop.

Any help or solution is appreciated!

**NB.** This is not [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604392/is-there-a-way-to-insert-an-encrypted-script-into-a-sql-server-database) of this question. Because there they are talking about encrypting specific variables and not an entire bulk of queries.

Comment: If your rival has access to your database on the customer server, can't they just inspect the final results? Also, how much of your "private IP" and "gold" is really found in those scripts? Do they have access to the client software as well? What my comment boils down to is this: Is it worth it?

Comment: We would like to have the query run in a blackbox. The results can be seen but the way we calculate them is also of value to us. Think of an "optimization problem" for instance.